# How can I display multiple images in one tensorboard tab like it's done in tf-object-detection-api

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I would like to create tensorboard image summaries using using `tf.Summary.Image` not using `tf.summary.image` and tensors. So it should be done without `tf.Session`. Currently I use this

```
    with BytesIO() as byte_io:
        img_crop_pil = Image.fromarray(image)
        img_crop_pil.save(byte_io, format="PNG")
        png_buffer = byte_io.getvalue()
    img_summary = tf.Summary.Image(encoded_image_string=png_buffer)
    return tf.Summary.Value(tag='img', image=img_summary)
```

And in tensorboard only one picture displayed. Slider is available but it is not convient especially with multiple steps.
I would like images to be displayed side by side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in the `tf.Summary.Value` `tag` parameter.
If you want several images in one tab you need this images to have tags in the following form. The most important part is the `/` in the tag name. It is parsed by tensorboard to split images inside tab

```
1st tab, 1st image - tf.Summary.Value(tag='tab_1/1', image=img_summary)  
1st tab, 2nd image - tf.Summary.Value(tag='tab_1/2', image=img_summary) 
1st tab, 3rd image - tf.Summary.Value(tag='tab_1/3', image=img_summary)

2nd tab, 1st image - tf.Summary.Value(tag='tab_2/1', image=img_summary)
2nd tab, 2nd image - tf.Summary.Value(tag='tab_2/2', image=img_summary)
2nd tab, 3rd image - tf.Summary.Value(tag='tab_2/3', image=img_summary)
and so on
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking in the documentation for this but had no success..